# Make a choice + what/whether?

Tags: grammar

Are these correct?

1: They made a choice WHAT to wear

2: They made a choice WHETHER to go to Italy or the UK.

Or should we write "They made a choice ABOUT what to wear" and "they made a choice ABOUT whether to go to Italy or the UK".

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> They made a choice ***of*** what to wear.

[See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+choice+of+what%2Ca+choice+what%2C+a+choice+about+what%2C+a+choice+of+whether%2C+a+choice+whether%2C+a+choice+about+whether&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20choice%20of%20what%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20choice%20what%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20choice%20about%20what%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20choice%20of%20whether%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20choice%20whether%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20choice%20about%20whether%3B%2Cc0). *"a choice of what ..."* is more common than *"a choice about what"*, and much more common than *"a choice what"*. For *"whether",* all of these options are closer in frequency.

Answer (score -1):

**WHAT**

They [made a choice] // [what to wear]. I would question whether this is correct although in spoken English it would be ok.  Subject + verb + [interrogative + to-infinitive] is the usual pattern. The phrase "what to wear" acts like the object. In this case you would use "to choose" rather than "to make a choice": "They chose what to wear."

Other examples:

- We decided where to go
- She wondered who to message next
- I know how to drive

They [made a choice about] // [what to wear]. This is better. The [what to wear] construction is like a noun phrase

- They made a choice about // eating pizza or pasta
- They made a choice about // the cat
- She made a choice about // who to speak to

**WHETHER**

They [made] [a choice] // [whether] [to go] [to Italy] // [or] [to the UK]. This is correct. This sentence answers the question: "Did they make a choice?" "Whether"/"or" are two conjunctions expressing alternatives similiar to "either/or", "both/and". Compare:

- I haven't decided whether to have the salad or the steak.
- I will be here whether you stay or go.

They made a choice about whether to go... answers the question ABOUT WHAT did they make a choice? It's also correct. The answer is "whether to go to Italy or the UK". The whole clause introduced by "whether" acts like a noun phrase. Compare:

- I have often thought about whether to get married or to stay single
- Sartre wrote a book on whether being or nothingness is more fundamental

Comment: Just on the first one, note you can often turn these singe word verbs into verb phrases with "hot" verbs like make, have, do; which still act like simple verbs. Eg choose ---> make a choice, decide ----> make a decision, know ---> have a knowledge of. Hence: They made a choice what to wear. We made a decision where to go. I have knowledge of how to drive. These are possible alternatives.